# Polling a database with items of different priority

Tags: lua

Given a list of items that have priorities ranging between 1 and 4 where one is the most important and 4 is the least important, how can I create a system that polls a central database for updates on the list of items, but polling the higher priority items more frequently than the lower priority items?

for example:
I have items a, b, and c that have priority values 1, 2, and three respectively.

In a perfectly functioning program, item a should be polling for updates more often than b and c, and b should be polling more frequently than c.

My main issue is designing a system in which all items are still polled regularly but the highest priority are polled more frequently.

Sorry I don't have more details but I don't really have any source code or anything to build off of, I'm kinda at a blank slate right now.

Also I'm working Lua, but I'm just looking for a rough pseudo-code version of ideas, I'd like to work out the exact implementation my self. For simplicity sake, polling the database can be represented by a method call: `getDatabaseInfo(itemIndex);`

All answers appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: you have to define what more often means. Is it a fixed ratio like poll a twice as often as b or is it time based like poll a continuoulsy but force 1 update on b every hour...  you should first write down exactly what you want to happen. don't worry about programming, just use your language. once you have that you can think about how to translate that into Lua

Comment: @piglet I *think* by more often he means what my code does. I can't be sure however.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you wish for each value to be updated, a loop like this could work.

- Things with primary priority are updated every time
- Things with secondary priority are updated every 2 cycles
- Things with tertiary priority are updated every 3 cycles
- Things with quaternary priority are updated every 4 cycles

Code:

```
for i = 1,math.huge do
    for ii = 1,#items do do
        if getPriority(ii) == 1 then
            items[ii] = getDatabaseInfo(ii)
        elseif i%2 == 0 and getPriority(ii) == 2 then
            items[ii] = getDatabaseInfo(ii)
        elseif i%3 == 0 and getPriority(ii) == 3 then
            items[ii] = getDatabaseInfo(ii)
        elseif i%4 == 0 and GetPriority(ii) == 4 then
            items[ii] = getDatabaseInfo(ii)
        end
    end
    sleep(interval)
end
```

The way this works is it does a check for if the current iteration number is divisible by 1,2,3, or 4.

One could add a 3rd nested loop which loops over all priorities, so you can have limitless amounts of priorities, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader :)

As noted by Piglet in the comments, you can use this shortcut to make the code more efficient:

```
if i % getPriority(ii) == 0 then ...
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, had no idea why code wasn't being formatted haha

Comment: you could simply write  `if i % getPriority(ii) == 0 then ...` you don't need all these elseifs.

Comment: While true I'm leaving the code in the simple/basic form it's in now, he didn't even want Lua code in the first place, so I'm leaving it in the easier to understand algorithm it is now. I'll include the shortcut tip if you want though.

Answer (score 0):

```
local items = {  -- all your items are here
   {name = "item #1", update_period = 1  },
   {name = "item #2", update_period = 1.5}, -- updates for item#2 will happen 1.5 times less frequent than updates for item#1
   {name = "item #3", update_period = 2  }, -- updates for item#3 will happen 2 times less frequent than updates for item#1
   {name = "item #4", update_period = 3  }, -- updates for item#4 will happen 3 times less frequent than updates for item#1
}

local function update_one_item()
   local min_ctr, itemIndex = math.huge
   for idx, item in ipairs(items) do
      item.current_counter = item.current_counter or 0
      if item.current_counter < min_ctr then
         min_ctr = item.current_counter
         itemIndex = idx
      end
   end
   for idx, item in ipairs(items) do
      item.current_counter = item.current_counter - min_ctr
   end
   items[itemIndex].current_counter = items[itemIndex].current_counter + items[itemIndex].update_period
   getDatabaseInfo(itemIndex);
   print(items[itemIndex].name.." updated")
end

for _ = 1, 20 do
   update_one_item()
end
```

Output:

```
item #1 updated
item #2 updated
item #3 updated
item #4 updated
item #1 updated
item #2 updated
item #1 updated
item #3 updated
item #1 updated
item #2 updated
item #4 updated
item #1 updated
item #3 updated
item #2 updated
item #1 updated
item #1 updated
item #2 updated
item #3 updated
item #4 updated
item #1 updated
```

Comment: No explanation on how the code works nor do you explain the method behind it like the reader asks. Downvoted.

Comment: @warspyking To be fair, well-written code can be understood even without explanation. The downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: @greatwolf To counter, someone who doesn't understand how to go about this problem is likely not experienced enough to read this code and understand without question. Additionally SO is a repository of Q&As, future readers who also want help will also be looking for an explanation, not just a code snippet that they don't even get the basics of. Also the asker of this question clearly *wanted* an explanation. Finally, I do not think this code is written in a simple enough way to be "understood without explanation". I will be leaving my vote as-is.

Comment: @warspyking to be honest your answer isn't that much easier to understand :)

Comment: @piglet I've explained *what* my code does and *how* it does it, along with using code that is understandable.